# C# textbox appointment

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

```
Random r = new Random();
int sayi = r.Next(1, 49);

textBox1.Text = sayi.ToString();
```

This code shows the first random number in `textbox1`, but I also need to get the output for the other textboxes as well:

```
(first click)--->Textbox1: 3
(second click)--->textbox2: 24
(third click)---> textbox3: 32
```

Comment: What's wrong with going on calling r.Next() and setting the .Text property of the extra textboxes?

Comment: Where do you store the references to your text boxes?

Comment: im new,dont understand what you mean? Grzenio
i want to show second random number in the textbox2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Declare Click Counter Global

private int clickCounter = 0;

// On Button Click Event
Random r = new Random();

if(clickCounter == 0)
{
textBox1.Text = Convert.ToInt32(r.Next(1,49));
clickCounter++;
}

if(clickCounter == 1)
{
textBox2.Text = Convert.ToInt32(r.Next(1,49));
clickCounter++;
}

if(clickCounter == 2)
{
textBox3.Text = Convert.ToInt32(r.Next(1,49));
clickCounter++;
}
```

This code block gives you what you want.

Comment: yeah that was what i am looking, tesekkurler serkan bey. gereksiz degil tıklamayı sayacak bir sey ariyodum bu yardimci olucak.

Comment: So you need to ask How can I track click count? :) Anyway, Im glad your problem solved. Good Luck. Iyi calismalar.

Comment: textBox1.Text = (r.Next(1,49).ToString()); is the right way. there is no need to convert integer..

Answer (score 0):

If you just have text boxes on your form (so that they are effectively fields in your Form class), you can add an int counter field to your class, initialize it to 0, and have (note: untested code):

```
Random r = new Random();
int sayi = r.Next(1, 49);
string textBoxName = "textBox"+counter;

FieldInfo fi = GetType().GetField(textBoxName);
TextBox currentTextBox = (TextBox)fi.GetValue();
currentTextBox.Text = sayi.ToString();
couter++;
```

plese note that this approach is rather ugly. It would be nicer to have these text boxes in a list or array and find them using the index instead of using the name of the field.